# loop index in R

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I wanna have my variable in loop like :

```
d1,d2,d3,...,d100
```

where di are vectors. how do I put them in loop in R :

```
for (i in 1:100){
paste0("d",i)= ....
}
```

This does not work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the objects in a `list` and then do the processing using `lapply`

```
lapply(mget(paste0("d", 1:100)), yourfunction)
```

---

`paste` is vectorized, so we don't need to use a `for` loop, but if we need to do the processing of the objects in a `for` loop and if we are creating objects in the global environment (not recommended)

```
for(i in 1:100) {
 assign(paste0("d", i), rnorm(5))
}
```

Instead of assigning multiple objects, the same operation can be done in a `list` without creating any objects

```
replicate(100, rnorm(5), simplify = FALSE)
```

Or

```
lapply(1:100, function(i) rnorm(5))
```

NOTE: `rnorm` is just for demonstration

Comment: I need this because I have 100 table, let say tab1 to tab100 as txt file, and I wanna read then in those d1 to d100 :  for(i in 1:100) { paste0("d",i)=read.table(paste0("tab",i,".txt")}

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini  You can do this by looping without creating 100 objects, i.e. `files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt"); lst <- lapply(files, read.table)` and then do the processign within the `list`  (here I assumed that the files are in working directory)